# how to call click function inside a while loop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, button, click

How to call click function inside a while loop in jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count=2;
  while(count>0){
    $(".box1").click();
    count--;
   }
   $(".box1").click(function(){
     var aud=document.createElement('audio');
     aud.src="tom-1.mp3";
     aud.play();
   });    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to specify `.box1` as `String`.
2. Attach the `event handler` before calling it.
3. Add `audio` to HTML. (Do not use virtually in javascript), Otherwise you get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. . now I am getting this error.` error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 2;

  $(".box1").click(function() {
    var aud = document.getElementById('audio');
    // replace with your audio
    aud.src = "https://freesound.org/data/previews/515/515391_1453392-lq.mp3";
    aud.play();
  });

  while (count > 0) {
    $(".box1").click();
    count--;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id='audio'></audio>
<button class='box1'>Play</button>
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.   .     now I am getting this error.